# How to select Icons in Dialog with IconPool from UI5

Tags: javascript, select, dialog, icons, sapui5

Hi I need help integrating the IconPool of UI5 in a SelectDialog with ValueHelp. You should be able to select all icons.

My code:
**Home.controller.js**

```js
handleValueHelp: function() {
    var loadDialog = this.loadFragment("myValueHelpFragment", this)
    loadDialog.then(function(oSelectHelpDialog){
        this.getView().addDependent(this.oSelectHelpDialog);
        var oBinding = oSelectHelpDialog.getBinding("items");
        oBinding.filter([]);
        oSelectHelpDialog.open();
    }.bind(this));
},
```

**ValueHelp.fragment.view**

```html
<core:FragmentDefinition
 xmlns="sap.m"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
 <SelectDialog
  noDataText="No Icons Found"
  title="Select Icon"
  search="handleSearch"
  liveChange="handleSearch"
  confirm="handleValueHelpClose"
  cancel="handleValueHelpClose"
  items="{
   path : '/icons'
  }">
  <StandardListItem
   id="iconInputHelpId"
   icon="{myModel>Icon}"
   title="{myModel>IconText}"/>
 </SelectDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

**Component.js**

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    icons: sap.ui.core.IconPool.getIconNames()
});
   
var oDialog = new sap.m.SelectDialog();
oDialog.setModel(oModel)
oModel.bindAggregation("items", {
    path: "/icons",
    factory: function(sId, oItem){
     return new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            key: oItem.getObject(), 
            title: oItem.getObject()
        })
    }
});

oDialog.open()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions in your code.

### Named models

You used a name for your model when binding the StandardListItem.

```xml
<StandardListItem
    id="iconInputHelpId"
    icon="{myModel>Icon}"
    title="{myModel>IconText}"/>
```

You did not, however, use that name when binding the items aggregation and when setting the model to the view in the first place.

```xml
items="{
    path : '/icons'
}">
```

```js
oDialog.setModel(oModel)
```

As @Bernard said you can either drop the name completely or use it consistently.

### Binding path

`IconPool.getIconNames()` returns a flat list of strings. So your model structure will look like this:

```js
{
    icons: [
        "accidental-leave", 
        "account", 
        "wrench", 
        "windows-doors", 
        "washing-machine",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Using your current binding (assuming the model name issue will be fixed) UI5 tries to load the following from your JSONModel:

```
"/icons/0/Icon"
"/icons/0/IconText"
```

But the items in your icons array do not have a property `Icon` or `IconText`. They are just strings!

Right now you have to build the icon path from scrath. This can be done directly in your XML.

```xml
<StandardListItem
    icon="sap-icon://{}"
    title="{}"/>
```

Using an empty path (which is a relative path since it does not begin with a `/`) will take the item as-is. In most cases this is not good because an item is an object with properties. In your case an item is a string, so that's perfect.

**That way you do not need a factory!**

Working example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/WY7mgge7RKHOfrRh

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "named model" (myModel) in your view for the field binding: `{myModel>Icon}`.
But you use the default model in your Component.js: `oDialog.setModel(oModel)`

Using this syntax should set your model to the named model you use in your XML View:

```
oDialog.setModel(oModel, "myModel")
```

You would also need to reference the named model in your items path.

```
items="{ path : 'myModel>/icons'}"
```

Alternatively simply remove the `myModel>` from `{myModel>Icon}` and `{myModel>IconText}` - as long as you have no other default model.

```
<StandardListItem
            id="iconInputHelpId"
            icon="{Icon}"
            title="{IconText}"/>
```